# I have a problem with using AWS secrets manager with Spring Boot app to get AWS RDS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, properties-file, aws-secrets-manager

this is my pom.xml dependencie that I'm using:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.secretsmanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-secretsmanager-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-secretsmanager-jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <aws-secretsmanager-jdbc.version>1.0.5</aws-secretsmanager-jdbc.version>
</properties>
```

this is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-classname=com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerPostgreSQLDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql://postgres-db.cjqt4bf02oy9.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres-db
spring.datasource.username=dev/dbCreds/demo
```

unfortunately I got this error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 6571600b-61bc-4889-ad74-f41c678bfd89; Proxy: null)
```

BTW I was following this article: [Spring Boot Externalized Database Configuration with AWS Secrets Manager](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-externalized-database-configuration-with-aws-secrets-manager-605f5ea3006a)

I have searched around but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Share more details on how are secrets stored in `dev/dbCreds/demo`

Comment: I went to the aws secrets manager console and created new secret and choose RDS database and then added my secrets (username and password) then I selected the database.

Comment: ```aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id dev/dbCreds/demo```
Check if credentials are present with correct key

Comment: yes indeed @NisargPatil I already checked and the secrets are there.